# Get the element clicked by user

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a big problem reading some pages on the internet. So I'm trying to make an Extension to ease my problem.

I just started, still learning everything I can do with the `manifest.json`.

BUt I'd like to know how may I get the element clicked by the user.

Like the extension `whatFont`, when you click on it's icon, you just have to hover the elements to know which font that's using... To do so, you have to read the element ( I guess).

How may I get the clicked element ? Just some tips/terms to search/anything... Thanks!

Comment: What about `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) { alert(e.target); });` ? In this case, `e.target` is the clicked element from body's tag.

Comment: @nicematt Do I just create a `file.js` ? How may I link it to the `manifest` ?

Comment: I never made a add-on, but you can check this link https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-make-a-chrome-extension, it has a example on how to include *.js.

Comment: See also [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4532236)

Comment: See also [Page Redder sample extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:redder) that showcases the bare minimum with a noninvasive modern approach ([`"activeTab"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab)).

Comment: Thanks, guys ! I understand a lot more about the types of files and how to link them. What I don't know yet is: Once I click my extension's icon, how may I make it wait for the user to click on a div or something...

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro, I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). It has overall background information which should help your understanding of how things are generally done/organized.

Comment: Guys. I kind made it :D I can edit the Body font size. The problem is: Sometimes editing the body font size, won't change the size of the letters you're reading, right ? How may I select the div ?  I'm reading everything you guys sent me, but Can't find how to specify the div

Comment: Now you're stuck with basic JavaScript stuff: modifying DOM. This is not something that can be answered in a couple of sentences. You need to study a tutorial or read a book on that.