# Read HTML page element value into Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a page called `Page1.html` held at http://intranet/ with the contents:

`<div id="username">my.username</div>`.

I'd like to use jQuery to read this value into my Chrome Extension.

Currently I have hard coded text: `document.getElementById("username").value="mcgurk"` in my `script.js` of my Chrome Extension but I'd prefer to grab the value in the `username` element.

---

Potentially useful:

I'm not great with Javascript but I did follow this tutorial a little: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?67448-document-getElementById-from-another-page which recommends something like this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $('#result').load('Page2.html #intro');
});
</script>
```

Their example works great but I'd like to build the above into a Chrome Extension.

Can anyone provide assistance for this issue?

Comment: Nah, that code snippet is pretty useless for the task. See [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4532236) for a condensed explanation with a small code example and many of existing answers for another approach: [extension content script popup messaging](https://www.google.com/#q=stackoverflow+extension+content+script+popup+messaging) for more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://intranet/index.php',
    success: function(html) {
        var nodes = $.parseHTML(html);
        var username = $("<div>").append(nodes).find("#username").text();
        $('#username').val(username);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#username').load('http://intranet/index.php',function() {
alert( "username was loaded successfully." );
});
```

Try to get the values using the load function in jquery