# How to access the original page from the Chrome extension JS file

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to figure out how to access in my `js` file the original page from the extension page.
Lets say I'm in `example.com/test.html`, I want to know how do I access test.html from my extension (the `download.js` which is been called from `download.html`)

**Edit:** So I've added another `js` script in the middle however I never reach the `download.js`

**Update** Thanks to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) I've manage to get what I wanted, I've updated the question for follow searches.

Here is my code:

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.min.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "download.js" }, function(results){

        JSON.stringify(results);

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < results[0].length; ++i) {
            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: results[0][i],
                filename: "/Users/testusr/Documents/"
                });
        }

     });
 });
```

download.js

```
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bimg] img'), function(e) { 
return e.src; 
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "This extension will download all product images",
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "download.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
"downloads"
   ]
}
```

download.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to inject script into the active tab. That is one of the [capabilities of the `"activeTab"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab#what-activeTab-allows).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532236/how-to-access-the-webpage-dom-rather-than-the-extension-page-dom)

Comment: As I use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` in `background.js` I don't reach the `download.js` file

Comment: Have you actually used console.log or debugging with a breakpoint? You should have seen an error that says chrome.downloads API isn't available in a content script. So you'll have to send the image url from the injected script back into the background page which will download it. See the example I've linked - the results are reported in `console.log(results[0])`

Comment: Yes of course I use (this how I was able to see I don't reach the download.js file). I didn't know that on the api, so I will move it to the outside js file as a return. But still I dont reach the download.js file..

Comment: Let me guess: your executeScript is called from browserAction.onClicked? It won't work when `default_popup` is declared in manifest.

Comment: No, without it. I tried to return a random string and I manage to get that string in the background.js however I never see the download.js in the debug window(therefor I don't know why my code return empty array with the original code).

Comment: Eh? So you use executeScript with null tabId parameter to inject into current page which is unpredictable when the extension starts its background page.

Comment: Guessing isn't fun, actually. Upload a zip of your extension, I'll take a look, usually it's instantly obvious in the debugger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136635/discussion-between-nir-and-woxxom).