# How To Get Input Value In Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a site which have this element :

```
<input type="text" id="editpane_title" fnk="tt" maxlength="80" name="title" value="st benedict crucifix">
```

And I want to get and set value of that input using Chrome Extension :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "demo",
  "icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
             "48": "icon48.png",
             "128": "icon128.png" },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "permissions": [ "tabs" ],

  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "24": "icon24.png",
        "32": "icon32.png"
      },
      "default_title": "demo"
    }
}
```

and here's `background.js` :

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {

        var title = document.getElementById('editpane_title').value;
        alert(title);

    });


});
```

and the alert is not showing up at all. I tried reload multiple times but still failed.

what did I missed here?

Comment: Either use a content script or use chrome.tabs.executeScript in background js.

Comment: Also Check th it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455598/get-input-value-chrome-extension/52455916#52455916

Comment: Also check the solution here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455598/get-input-value-chrome-extension/52455916#52455916](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455598/get-input-value-chrome-extension/52455916#52455916)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two issues here.

First off, code not working and you have no idea why.

> alert is not showing up at all

**You need to learn to debug extensions to understand what's wrong.** Trying to solve the problem yourself is important even if you fail to do so. There's Google's own somewhat dated [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) that mostly covers popups, and there's this canonical question for background scripts:

**[Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension)**

---

So suppose you follow the advice and try debugging. You will quickly learn that `alert` is not called, because there's an exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

That leads to a second problem: **`document.getElementById('editpane_title')` can't find the element.**

Ask yourself: *which* `document` is referenced here? Or rather, why would it automagically be the page you're looking at?

At this point, you should read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). You'll learn there:

- The background scripts actually live in a separate, invisible tab in their own document.
- To access a visible page's `document`, you need a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).
- To pass data between them, you have to employ [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and/or [`storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

[image: Extension architecture]

Armed with that knowledge, you should now turn to the following canonical question:

**[How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532236/how-to-access-the-webpage-dom-rather-than-the-extension-page-dom/)**

---

As a final point, you should not be using `alert` to inspect the state of your program, or for any reason really.

This ancient mechanism is *blocking*: it stops JS context from doing anything until you dismiss the modal window. This screws up with some extension APIs that are asynchronous and interface with native components of the browser.

In fact, in Firefox WebExtensions you [expicitly can't use them from a background page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#Additional_incompatibilities).

So, wean off this bad habit early:

- The equivalent of `printf`/`echo`-style debugging is `console.log()`, with the output accessible as explained in the debugging section.
- To alert the user, you should seek other UI capabilities, such as notifications.