# Chrome Extension: How to run my content.js in actual webpage instead of popup.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a extension that is doing all kind of stuff with any given website. Everything worked well before i added popup window in purpose to use it as some kind of UI for the extension. After i have found it impossible to get my code run anywhere outside of that popup..

This sample is from my previous unsuccessful try:

HTML is just a start (starts initSession function) and stop button with access to content.js. I'am looking for solution (if there is a one) where i don't have to inject the actual page and could handle this with messages somehow..

content.js:

```
function initSession() {
    window.close(); //popup..
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        message: 'popup_closed'
    }, function(response) {
        var response = response.message;
        if(response === "ready_to_record")
            startRecording();
    });
}

function startRecording(){
    createListeners();
}
```

//background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse, tab) {

    if (request.message == "popup_closed")
        sendResponse({message: "ready_to_record"});

});
```

Comment: startRecording function creates eventlisteners always to popup.html.. or in this particular case it doesnt create anything anywhere as popup is already closed..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532236/how-to-access-the-webpage-dom-rather-than-the-extension-page-dom)