# How to find text-boxes from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, css-selectors

I'm making a Chrome extension and I need it to find any form text-boxes on the webpage.

I first tried doing it in my content script like:

```
document.getElementsByTag("text");
```

But it always returns `undefined` so I'm assuming it's searching only `my_app.html`.

My first question is what function should I use: GetElmentsByTag, by name, by className, or with some other function?

My second question is which JavaScript file do I need to search? Other forums with similar problems said you need to access the DOM in another file like background or popup and then send it to the content script with a message and a listener.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532236/how-to-access-the-webpage-dom-rather-than-the-extension-page-dom)

Comment: It's also really important to read the extension overview in the  documentation, which explains the basic architecture so you won't be confused about it and get weird ideas.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are calling a function that doesn't exist. You probably mean [`Document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) or [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), as you can see here:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName);
console.log(document.querySelectorAll);
console.log(document.getElementsByTag);
```

Also, your selector is wrong: There's no `<text>` HTML element.

If you want all [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) fields, with any `type` attribute (`text`, `password`, `search`, `radio`, `checkbox`, ...) then you could use any of these:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input');

document.querySelectorAll('input');
```

If you just want `<input>`s of a specific type, let's say `text`, you could do:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')
```

Lastly, you can concatenate multiple selectors with `,` if you want `<input>`s of different types:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]')
```