# Access to page content from extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a button on the extension to click on a link from a certain page, I managed to do some stuff but still can't gain access to the content of the page, here's what i did so far :

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
    if(changeInfo && changeInfo.status == "complete"){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "jquery.js"}, function(){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "main.js"});
        });
    }
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
 {
  "name": "ext",
  "version": "2.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "ext desc",
  "icons" : {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "38": "icons/icon38.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": 
     {
   "default_icon": "icons/icon16.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
      "matches" :  ["<all_url>"],
      "persistent":true,
      "scripts": [ "background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*", "file://*/*"],
      "css": ["src/custom.css"],
      "js": ["background.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["background.js"]

}
```

Comment: I bet you didn't intend to put `background.js` into your `content_scripts`. You can just directly insert jquery.js and main.js into content_scripts.

Comment: shouldn't I? sorry still new to this

Comment: The background script is something that runs separated from the tabs. If you close your tab, your background script stays alive, and even if you have 2 tabs, there is only 1 background script executing.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that, although still have an issue accessing to the current page content.

Answer (score 0):

If you just intend to inject `main.js` and `jquery.js` into every tab, then you can just change your `content_scripts` to the following:

```
{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "main.js"]
}
```

Note that I fixed the `"matches"` as well: `"<all_urls>"` already covers all possible urls.

Also, note that `"background.js"` does not belong into `"web_accessible_resources"`. This is a place for things such as images that are in your WebExtension folder you wish to display in websites.

**EDIT**: A very similar problem has been solved in [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532236), you cannot directly access the tab's page from your popup. To do this, you have to either use the messaging API, or inject code (as shown in the answer).
I also found that you have another typo in your `background` `matches`: I am pretty sure you forgot to add an 's' to `<all_url>`.

Comment: Yes i am, the content is changing on the extension content, but i want to change it on the web content, per example if i wanted to change the body color, it only changes the extension body not web page body.

Comment: @aqweeb.com Extension body? Are you referring to the extension's popup?

Comment: Yes i'm using a popup.html

Comment: @aqweeb.com So you're trying to access the tab's page from the popup page?

Comment: Yes exactly that's it