# How do I go about getting a value from a function in executeScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to modify a webextension and running into problems. I have this in `background.js`:

```
function capture(comment: ?string = null, tag_str: ?string = null) {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true }, tabs => {
        const tab = tabs[0];
        if (tab.url == null) {
            showNotification('ERROR: trying to capture null');
            return;
        }
        const url: string = tab.url;
        const title: ?string = tab.title;

        get_options(opts => {
               chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
                // code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
                // file: "copy.js"
                code: "textget();"
            }, selections => {
                const selection = selections == null ? null : selections[0];
                makeCaptureRequest({
                    url: url,
                    title: title,
                    selection: selection,
                    comment: comment,
                    tag_str: tag_str,
                }, opts);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

And I want to use the output from the function textget() in another function (`makeCaptureRequest`). textget() needs to be executed in the browser, hence it is inside `executeScript`.
I've tried a file too, and that didn't work either.

`// code: "window.getSelection().toString();"` this was the original code in the function.

the function `textget()` does return something, and it's like this in `copy.js`

```
function textget() {
    let title = window.title;
    if (options.titleSubstitution !== "") {
      let pattern = new RegExp(
        options.titleSubstitution
          .split(/\n/)
          .map(e => `(${RegexEscape(e)})`)
          .join("|"),
        "g"
      );
      title = title.replace(pattern, "");
    }
    let text = options.linkWithoutStyling ? `${title} (${window.URL})` : `[${title}](${window.URL})`;
    let selectionNew = getSelectionAsMarkdown(options);

    if (selectionNew.output !== "") {
      if (options["use-quote"]) {
        selectionNew.output = selectionNew.output
          .split("\n")
          .map(line => `> ${line}`)
          .join("\n");
      }
      if (options["link-to-source"]) {
        text += `\n\n${selectionNew.output}`;
      } else {
        text = selectionNew.output;
      }
    }

    return text;
}
export{textget};
```

And `background.js` imports it
`import { textget } from "./copy"`

Whatever I do, `selection` is always empty. I want the value in it to match `text` from the imported function.

Comment: The first line of copy.js should be `window.textget = () => {` and no need for the last `export`, no need to import it in background.js

Comment: I would then have to use `file: "copy.js"`, right?

Comment: I thought you already load it in manifest.json using `content_scripts`. If you don't then you can use `code` with a stringified function ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)) - in your case inContent will be textget)

Comment: So I don't have to use `window.textget = () => {`, right? My code looks like this now: `chrome.tabs.executeScript( {code: \`(${ textget })\`}, selections => { \\rest unchanged`

Comment: Right now, the only line I'm changing is `code: "window.getSelection().toString();"` to `\code: `(${ textget })\``, but it doesn't work. I suppose there's something else broken...
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't notice that you've deleted half of the string. You need to add `()` so it looks like \`(${ textget })()\`