# What's the permition to access to website data from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I am doing a chrome extension that allows downloading images from Instagram (Save image as).

I already saw some similar questions but I didn't understand the answers. 
Here is the code:
json:

```
    {
  "name": "Image Allower",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Remove images from websites",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Allow Images</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="submit" align="center" style="width: 470px" id="button">Allow Download</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', remove);

function remove() {
document.querySelectorAll('._9AhH0').forEach(function(a){
    a.remove();
})
}
```

(As you can see, I'm not very good at this... )
Thanks

Comment: [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)