# Chrome extension repeatedly rejected for only three permissions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions, manifest.json

This is my first time making a Chrome extension so apologies if this is real basic but I can't find answers and/or don't know enough about what I'm doing.

My extension keeps getting rejected for permissions, most recently "Requesting permissions that are not used. Requesting permissions that are not required for the item’s stated functionality."

The extension is meant to run on any active tab (with user trigger), uses sessionStorage and grabs some images from my website, thus the permissions I've included.  Am I using the wrong terms?

My manifest:

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Disc",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "Extension, Results vary",
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["jquery.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  
  "icons": { 
        "16": "icons/16.png",
        "19": "icons/19.png",
        "32": "icons/32.png",
        "38": "icons/38.png",
        "48": "icons/48.png",
        "128": "icons/128.png"
    },
  
  "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "jquery-ui.min.js", "jquery.visible.min.js", "highlight.js", "discernment.js"],
        "css": ["disc.css"]
        }
    ],
    
   "permissions": [ "https://dinakelberman.com/", "activeTab", "storage"],
    
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "icon.svg",
        "house.png",
        "mouse.png",
        "pointer.png",
        "none.png",
        "wiki/wiki.ico",
        "wiki/truefalse.html",
        "wiki/truefalse.css",
        "wiki/highlight.js",
        "wiki/enwiki.png",
        "wiki/download.svg",
        "wiki/wikimedia-button.png",
        "wiki/40px-Wiktionary-logo-en-v2.svg.png",
        "wiki/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png",
        "wiki/cog-sprite.svg",
        "wiki/Disambig_gray.svg.png",
        "wiki/compact-links-trigger.svg",
        "wiki/user-avatar.svg",
        "wiki/search.svg",
        "wiki/bullet-icon.svg",
        "fonts/coexist-webfont.ttf",
        "fonts/coexist-webfont.woff",
        "fonts/coexist-webfont.eot",
        "fonts/Lot-Regular.otf",
        "fonts/Lot-Regular.ttf", 
        "truefalsescreen.png",
        "fonts/logo-font.ttf"
    ],
    
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/48.png"
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your content scripts run on all sites, which is effectively the same as having `"*://*/*"` in permissions. Depending on what your content script does, this may be an extreme overkill e.g. maybe you don't need a content script running by default prior to user interaction with your extension icon. If you do need this broad permission then you need to describe the need for this explicitly.

Comment: Switch to [programmatic injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532567).