# I want to do DOM manipulation in my chrome extension using chrome.commands

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension where I can use key commands on specific pages (Eg: "Ctrl+Shift+A") which then triggers some DOM manipulation code (such as clicking a button).

But the issue I am facing is that "chrome.commands" runs in the background environment (background property in manifest.json) and If I include "chrome.commands.onCommand" in content_scripts (inside manifest.json) I get this error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCommand' of undefined`.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two scripts. The [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) registers a `chrome.commands` listener which injects a [content script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532567) (or sends a message to a content script declared in manifest.json). The content script runs in the web page and has access to its DOM.