# How can I get "document.cookie" of a current tab from a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

This is what I've been trying to do in the console of the extension:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "document.cookie"})
```

But for some reason, it always ends up returning "undefined" in the console logs. Is there a reason for this, or a way to get all the cookies on the current tab the extension is on?

This is my manifest.json:

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "Sample Description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "windows",
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't using the result. You need to add a callback and use the returned value there ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)). Also note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Yeah I understand about the inspecting in the extension's devtools. I'm not really experienced in JavaScript, mostly in Python. Are you able to send an example of what a callback for printing the values would look like for reference?

Comment: An example is linked in my comment.