# Could not establish connection with content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am new to Chrome extension, I tried to write a test extension, the messaging between the popup page and background page works as expected, but when I try to send message from popup to content script, there is always the error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", this may means there is no registered listener. I check the code again and again in the popup and content script files, but can't find where is wrong. Thank you for help!

Here are  the files:

```
manifest.json:

{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    
    "name": "Chrome extension test 01",
    "description": "test extension messaging",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "permissions": [ "tabs", "activeTab", "https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
    
    "icons": {
        "128": "images/icon128.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Here is the extension icon title",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/icon16.png",
            "32": "images/icon32.png",
            "48": "images/icon48.png"
            }
        },  
        
    "content_scripts": 
        [ 
            {
            "matches":  ["<all_urls>"],  
            "js": ["content.js"]
            }
        ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
        }   

}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Test extension for chrome</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Chrome extension messaging test</h3>
<div>
    <!--  Display message sent from backgroud: "This is the message sent from the background"  -->
    <p id="showMsg"></p>
</div>  

<h2 id="test02">click to test messaging (content script)</h2>

<script ype="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
//popup.js

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        document.getElementById("showMsg").innerText=response.data;
    });
    
});


document.getElementById("test02").addEventListener('click', function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {cmd: "GetSelectedText"}, function(response)
            {
                if(response.res)
                    alert(response.res);
            }); 
    });

});
```

background.js

```
//background.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        if(request.greeting=="hello"){
            sendResponse({data: "This is the message sent from the background."});
        }
        
    return true;         //send a response asynchronously, this will keep the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called.
    }
);
```

content.js

```
// content.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.cmd=="GetSelectedText")
    {
        var selectedText=window.getSelection().toString().trim();
        if(selectedText&&selectedText.length)
        {
            console.log(selectedText);
            sendResponse({res: selectedText});
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}};
```

Comment: The error means the content script wasn't running when you opened the popup which may happen if you reloaded the extension without reloading the tab or the tab is still loading. While both problems have a workaround, but there's a much better proper solution: programmatic injection ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)). It replaces both `content_scripts` declaration and messaging.

Comment: Thank you for your message, I tried to reload the extension and reload the tab, but the error still occurred. I will try programmatic injection in the content script.

Comment: I have tried chrome.runtime.executeScript(), it works. But the code in the above post can not work, I can't find what is wrong.