# How do I get a checkbox value from popup to make it change page's CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

everyone.
Basically, this streaming website displays 4:3 videos in 16:9, ignoring the aspect ratio and making them all stretched. I checked and the videos were pre-streched, since their resolution is 1024x576.

Nevertheless, I found a way to make them 4:3, which is adding `transform: scaleX(0.75)` to the class `playkit-container`.

To make things more easier, I'm trying to make a simple Chrome extension with a popup that has a checkbox. If the checkbox is checked, the javascript should add `transform: scaleX(0.75)` to `playkit-container`. If is not checked, it should, either reset the CSS or set it to `transform: scaleX(1.0)`.

Here's what I have:

**extension.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Opto AR Fixer</h1>
    <p>Fixes the AR of 4:3 episodes streaming on Opto.</p>

    <input type="checkbox" name="forcear" id="forcear">
    <label for="forcear">Force 4:3</label>
    <script src="extension.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**extension.js**

```
var popup = chrome.extension.getViews({type:"popup"})[0];
var checkBox = popup.document.getElementById("forcear").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {  
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        document.getElementsByClassName("playkit-container")[0].style.transform = "scaleX(0.75)"
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("playkit-container")[0].style.transform = "scaleX(1.0)"
    }
  }
```

However, nothing happens. If I inspect the popup and check the logs, whenever I click the button it throws me these errors:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined`

`Uncaught TypeError: chrome.extension.getViews is not a function`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It is saying the owner of the property 'checked' is undefined. When you defined your `checkBox`, you assigned it to the .addEventListener() which is returning nothing. So this is means `checkBox` is assignd as 'undefined'.

You will want to split up your variable assignment to just the element itself, and then assign the even listener separately in this case.

e.g.

```
var popup = chrome.extension.getViews({type:"popup"})[0];
var checkBox = popup.document.getElementById("forcear");

checkBox.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {  
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        document.getElementsByClassName("playkit-container")[0].style.transform = "scaleX(0.75)"
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("playkit-container")[0].style.transform = "scaleX(1.0)"
    }
  }
```

Find el on page loop:

```
function findEl() {
  setTimeout((){ 
    const el = document.getElementsByClassName("playkit-container")[0];
    if (el.length > 0) {
      // do other logic once el is found if needed
    } else {
      findEl();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I rewrote the code like you suggested, but now it throws me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`.
I doubled checked, and the class name is correct. Should I wait for the DOM to load?

Comment: Since the example does not show where 'playkit-container' is defined it's hard to tell. I'm assuming that's where the error is coming from.  If you are hitting this error after `myFunction` is called, the only thing I can say is add a debugger or console log and check for `document.getElementsByClassName("playkit-container")`. Or if you can create a code example we can work off that.

Comment: I've been trying a lot of different things, since yesterday. Fortunately, I did what you suggested, the `console.log()` thing, and I understood what was the problem. It was throwing me that error, because he was searching in the extension's DOM, for some reason.

I still didn't fix it, but I managed to simplify things. Now I have a `popup.js` that gets the popups checkbox, listens to it and calls a function called `forceAR()` which is in `content.js`. Now my problem is that it won't find that function.

The website is geo-blocked and needs a login. What's the best way to show you the DOM?

Comment: Ok sorry for getting back to you. Check this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532236/how-to-access-the-webpage-dom-rather-than-the-extension-page-dom . 


Another possible option, we could try applying a loop on your extension say every 1 second. If it finds the element when the page is loaded, then run the script. Updated above ^