# How to pass parameters when using "chrome.tabs.executeScript()"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in my Chrome Extension.

```
function convert(info,tab) {
     function modifyDOM(tab) {
         //code that wants access to the tab parameter from convert()
     }
     chrome.tabs.executeScript({
           code: '(' + modifyDOM + ')();' 
           }, (results) => {
             console.log(results[0]);
     });
 }
```

I want to pass the "tab" parameter from convert() into modifyDOM(), but everything I have tried has failed and I am out of ideas.

I tried doing something like this, but that results in an error.

```
code: '(' + modifyDOM + ')(' + tab + ');'
```

> VM581:31 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I also tried adding a query in modifyDOM(), but that threw an error as well.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
    console.log(tab);
});
```

> VM580:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
> at modifyDOM (:3:19)
> at :37:7

Comment: Use JSON.stringify, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532567).

Comment: @wOxxOm - Thank you sir.