# Manifest v3 inject script from popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In manifest v2 this code worked and injected the script when button was clicked:

popup.js v2 (works)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
// Get button by ID
var button = document.getElementById('btnScan');

// Define button on click action
button.onclick = function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'Scripts/script.js'
    });
    window.close();
    }
});
```

Now in manifest v3, `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is replaced with `chrome.scripting.executeScript`.

`scripting` permission is added in `manifest.json`.

popup.js v3 (not working)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
// Get button by ID
var button = document.getElementById('btnScan');

// Define Scan button on click action
button.onclick = function () {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript
        (
        {
            target: { tabId: null}, // ???????
            files: ['Scripts/script.js']
        }
        );
    window.close();
    }
});
```

The problem is that `chrome.tabs.executeScript` requires `tabId` value as one of the parameters.
How can I get `tabId` value in `popup.js` or convert the manifest v2 version javascript so that it works the same?

Comment: Get the active tab and use its `id`, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67227376).

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I knew I had to do something like that, but I couldn't find the example you posted. I will post solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @wOxxOm who posted a link as a comment.

The solution was to get the active tab and use its `tabId`.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Get button by ID
    var button = document.getElementById('btnScan');
    button.onclick = injectScript;
});

async function injectScript() {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
    await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    files: ['Scripts/script.js']
    });
    window.close();
}
```