# connect a service worker to a content script

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

In short, I want that when you press my extension button from the context menu, the content script will be added to the web page temporarily. I tried to use sendMessage() but it just didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated:)

```js
//This is the service worker (eventPage)

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'select',
    title: 'select',
    type: 'normal',
    contexts: ['all']
  });
})
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickDate) {
  if (clickDate.menuItemId == 'select') {
    //send message to make content-script start operate
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('start');

  }
});
```

---

```
//let's say that this is the content-script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse) {

  if (response == 'start') {

    // js code that is inserted into the site
  }
});
```

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,

"name": "SendFast",
"description": "This extension makes it easier to send information",
"version": "1.0",
"icons": {
  "128": "16-nahum.png",
  "48": "64-nahum.png",
  "16": "16-nahum.png"
},

"action": {
  "default_icon": "16-nahum.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions":["contextMenus","activeTab"],


"background":{
  "service_worker": "eventPage.js"
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content-script.js"]
  }
]
```

}

so I tried to use chrome.scripting but failed. that's what I came up with:

```js
//eventPage.js(after changes)

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
 chrome.contextMenus.create({
   id: 'select',
   title: 'select',
   type: 'normal',
   contexts: ['all']
 });

})


async function addJsScript() {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    script:["content-script"],
  });
}
  
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickDate) {
  if (clickDate.menuItemId == 'select') {

    addJsScript()
  
  }
});
```

and i added this to the manifest:

```
    "permissions":["contextMenus","activeTab","scripting"],
"host_permissions":["<all_urls>"],
```

Comment: Remove `content_scripts` from manifest.json and use [chrome.scripting](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/) API instead. Your injected code won't need onMessage, it'll run immediately when injected, see [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67227376).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, i will try to implement those changes.

Comment: hey I have added the changes above, could you please take a look?

Comment: Add `.js` to the file name in executeScript. See also [How to see background.js console?](/a/10258029)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems that I have been having that is related to this. Here's what you need to know.

First, to access the tabs, you need to add `"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]` to your manifest (v3) to assure that you can access the web pages.

Second, instead of `script:["content-script.js"]` as seen in the `addJsScript()` function, use `files:["content-script.js"]`.

Lastly, make sure you have the `scripting` permission added in your manifest file.

That is what I had to do to fix it for me.

Also, as stated above, remove the content script from your manifest and add .js to the end of the script name in `files`