# Send input text from contentScipt to popup html Chrome Extension built using angular

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I built a Chrome extension using angular. But I encourted an issue in regard to send data from contentscript to popup.
any tips for sending data from input tag to display in popup?
Thanks

Comment: Use messaging or executeScript, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4532236). If you need further assistance, add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. First, send the message from **contentScript** file

   ```
   var type = e.detail.type; // a "key" for your data
   var data = e.detail.data;

   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: type, data: data});
   ```
2. Now you can get message in your Angular app

   ```
   /// <reference types="chrome"/>

   if (chrome.runtime) {
       chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
           const type = message.type;
           const data = message.data;

           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               // Write your codes
           });
       });
   }
   ```

   Be sure to add the following code to the top of your TS or JS file

   ```
   <reference types="chrome"/>
   ```

Note: If **chrome.runtime** has as error, then you can install this **npm** package to fix it

```
npm install @types/chrome --save-dev
```