# Dynamic change of Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've got quite a simple task. On one of websites I need to get local storage data and for now just display it in my extension widget.
That is a screen from popup.html which represents the UI of the extension. With red color I show `div` block where I would like to display data from Local Storage

[image]

That is the screen of function which takes data from Local Storage and should insert it in the div

[[image]

And this is the error I get when I try to display data

[[image]

Project in general
[image: project content]
[image: popup.html]
[image: popup.js]

Could somebody explain where I miss something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error says you need to define `textField` variable. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, but it’s defined in popup.js at the very top(

Comment: Judging by the error it is not defined correctly. Please show the code properly as text.

Comment: added screens of the project

Comment: executeScript runs the code in the web page, which is not related to the popup page so it can't access variables or elements of the popup page. You should separate the code that runs in the web page from the code that uses the result. Example: [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67227376)