# How can I get a localstorage of a webpage using a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, local-storage, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to make a browser extension, when I click a button to get an API key stored in the local storage of a website. I have observed that I'm able to get the API key outside the event listener. However, when I do it inside of it always returns `null`. I was told that inside the event listener it is trying to get the local storage of the browser extension, so what can I do to overcome this issue? (I'm new to browser extensions)

**Javascript**:

```
let id = window.localStorage.getItem("session_id");
console.log(id)


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var api_button = document.getElementById('api_button');
    // onClick's logic below:
    api_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        id = window.localStorage.getItem("session_id");
        alert(id)

    });
});
```

Comment: It probably means the site clears the id when that button is clicked. You can try running your code earlier by adding `,true` like this: api_button.addEventListener('click', function(){ ..... }, true)

Comment: When I try that it still returns ``null``, I think what the issue is the id does the exist in the extension storage. However I'm not sure how to access the website local storage from inside of the EventListener.

Comment: See [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4532236)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage) API for this.

In your manifest.json, you need `storage` [permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions)

```
"permissions": [
  "storage"
]
```

and then in your extension code, you can access the local storage with

```js
browser.storage.local.set({ session_id: 'example' })

browser.storage.local.get('session_id').then((session_id) => {
    console.log(session_id)
})
```