# Chrome async wait sending content before request completed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await, google-chrome-devtools

Below is an attempt to extract some information from a webpage and then display it on a Chrome extension page.

The problem I have based on many hours of research seems to be that the sending of variable extracted from webpage to extension page failed as my extractor is asynchronous.

The variable that arrives at my extension page after the last step below is [object object].

It seems that the sendMessage action doesn't wait for async-wait step to finish before sending results to the receiving end.
I have tried many fixes from Stack Overflow answers, but I just don't seem to find a solution.

1.) This code will run on the webpage to extract some information (the async await is needed in original code, and the below is just a sample).

```
async function Extractor(document) {
    var item = document.getElementbyId("....");
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));

    return item
}
```

2.) I assume this code sends the message to the one below telling it to run and retrieve extractor results.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: Extractor(document)
});
```

3.) This code is in *popup.js*, where my intention is to insert the extractor's result from webpage into a *popup.html* extension page, under node id = "message".

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
   if (request.action == "getSource") {
      message.innerText = request.source;
   }
});
```

Comment: You can't send a DOM element, you can send its `textContent` or `innerHTML` properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tested that and still it doens't work. Only when I remove the asycronous method it works. So I am quite sure the issue is with that..?

Comment: That bug was that his code doesn't run. I think for mine, it runs, but the coordination is wrong. The sendMessage action doesn't wait for the async-wait function to finish before sending results to the receiving end.

Comment: Ah, indeed, you need to add `await` before calling Extractor. And you should probably use executeScript as explained here: [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4532236)

Comment: The returned item result in step 1 is fine. The issue seems to be Step 2 & Step 3.

Comment: No, messaging can't send DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample displays *document.title* in a popup.

#### File *popup.js*

```js
const message = document.getElementById("message");

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
    function: getDocumentTitle
  });
});

async function getDocumentTitle() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: await Extractor()
  });

  async function Extractor() {
    var item = document.title;
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));

    return item;
  }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender) {
  if (request.action == "getSource") {
    message.innerText = request.source;
  }
});
```

#### File *manifest.json*

```json
{
  "name": "getDocumentTitle",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

#### File *popup.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="message"></div>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Norio Yamamoto!! 
This solved the issue.

Key part was to implement this correctly:


async function getDocumentTitle() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: await Extractor()
  });

  async function Extractor() {
    var item = document.title;
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));

    return item;
  }
}