# How to access the main HTML document from a pyscript browser extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser, pyscript

I am trying to create a browser extension following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@petefison/write-chrome-extensions-in-python-6c6b0e2e1573) and I want to create an extension which can access the actual document and ideally all the network (requests etc.).

But when I print out the `documentURL` from `document`

```
print(document.documentURI)
```

inside `index.html` I get the URI of the extension itself (like `chrome-extension://enlpckinaieecgmjgamlcbicmjiahkkf/index.html`) and not for the webpage it is running on.

How to "access" the actual webpage?

Comment: [How to access the webpage DOM/HTML from an extension popup or background script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4532236)

Comment: Thanks, but the page linked in that answer does not explain how to download the script `contentScript.js`...

Comment: There's no need to download it, the answer describes a complete solution, but I don't know how to apply it to your case of using python.

Comment: Maybe pyscript is not the best choice for what I want to do actually.