# Error on javascript with a google chrome extension i try to devellop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, error-handling

Hello i'm tryin to devellop an extension aiming at help readers with dyslexia when they navigate the web.

The functionning of it would be to change the colors of lines alternating between blue and red to help them follow the lines.

The error i'm encountering is as follow:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
```

Here are the code of the 4 files i'm using to achieve that, if anyone's willing to help i'd be thankfull.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Extension Texte Rouge et Bleu",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Change la couleur du texte d'une ligne sur deux en rouge et bleu.",
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "img/icon_16.png",
        "48": "img/icon_32.png",
        "128": "img/icon_128.png"
      }
    }
  }
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Extension Texte Rouge et Bleu</h1>
    <button id="colorizeButton">Colorize</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.getElementById('colorizeButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
    let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');
    for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            paragraphs[i].style.color = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
        } else {
            paragraphs[i].style.color = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
        }
    }
});
```

**popup.css**

```
body {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

button {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

I'm just expecting a bit of help, i can't understand why this error occurs and haven't tried a lot of things.

Comment: 1) Move the `<script` line to the end of html or add `defer` attribute. 2) See [Accessing \`window\`/DOM/HTML of the webpage from the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67227376)

Comment: Hi, i've moved the call of the script down in the body oy my HTML, but still got the same result, can you enlight me on the second part of your answer (i must confess i'm a total "nooby" on programming in generat) i can't process what to do with that... sorry to bother.

Comment: Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. Switch to the Sources panel and debug your code.

Comment: Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15
document.getElementById('colorizeButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
I now got two different error, i've seen that even on the google groups you've answered questions like those, but i can't process how those apply to my problem... Sorry might be dumb

Comment: The service worker can't use `document` or `window`. This code should be in the popup script. Note that you don't need the service worker at all for this task.